# How do you save images of detected objects in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, save-image

I am trying to add "if, then logic" to the opencv face detection code such that if and when a face is detected through a camera or webcam, an image of the detected face is saved to a pre-determined file path on the controller or computer such as C:\Users\Public\Desktop.

I have looked everywhere for examples of anything that can help but I cant find anything.

If anyone knows any codes, research articles, websites, people I can contact, that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call that detects the face will most probably contain a `boundingRectangle` parameter of type `vector<Rect>`. Use the data present in it to select the Region of Interest(ROI) if a face is detected. This selected ROI can then be saved using [this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=save%20image#imwrite).

These are the very basics of OpenCV and hence I am not including any code snippets along with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the detected portion(pending whether you are getting a region or point) from the image, define an roi(if needed). Then copy the roi to new image and then save to path?